# problem in Refresh the pageblock with autocompletion taking long time?

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

This is the autocompletion script :

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
            $( ".AutoPin" ).autocomplete({
                source: function( request, response ) {
                         var matcher = new RegExp( "^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex( request.term ), "i" );
                         var arr = $.grep( {!jsonDescriptionData}, function( item ){  return matcher.test( item );    })
                         if(arr.length == 0)
                         arr[0] = 'To Be Defined';
                         response( arr );
                },
            minLength:2,

           change: function( event, ui ) {myFunction5($('#Nico'+nicopinClient ).find('input').val());click1()}

        });
        </script>
```

This is the input field :

```
<apex:inputField value="{!qli.Name}" id="Name" style="width:110px"   StyleClass="AutoPin" onclick="javascript: nicopinClient  = '{!(ROUND(rowNum,0))}'; " >
```

In my page i am using list so input field will be coming multiple times

Unless i refresh above java script for every button it is not not working for the list input field auto completion (it is very much time taking to refresh page )

If i kept inputfield as

```
<apex:inputField value="{!qli.Name}" id="Name" style="width:110px"   StyleClass="AutoPin" >
```

It is show autocompletion for all list input fields but i need to call this:

```
function "onclick="javascript: nicopinClient  = '{!(ROUND(rowNum,0))}'; "
```

I want to do this without calling this onclick on input field and it should directly pass value to nicopinclient.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
            $( ".AutoPin" ).autocomplete({
                source: function( request, response ) {
                         var matcher = new RegExp( "^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex( request.term ), "i" );
                         var arr = $.grep( {!jsonDescriptionData}, function( item ){  return matcher.test( item );    })
                         if(arr.length == 0)
                         arr[0] = 'To Be Defined';
                         response( arr );
                },
            minLength:2,

           change: function( event, ui ) {myFunction5($('#Nico'+nicopinClient ).find('input').val());click1()}

        });
        </script>
```

In the above script I need help with pass value directly with out using onclick.